# URLSessionWebSocketTask.receive() doesn't throw on cancel()

Tags: ios, urlsessionwebsockettask

I am repeatedly calling `URLSessionWebSocketTask.receive`. I've tried recursively calling [the version with the completion handler](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessionwebsockettask/3281789-receive), as well as looping over [the new async version](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessionwebsockettask/3767359-receive).

At some point, I'm not receiving any more messages, and I want to cancel the web socket. So I call `URLSessionWebSocketTask.cancel()`. In the log, I see the message `[websocket] Read completed with an error Operation canceled`. But the completion handler is never called/the async receive method never returns. This means that the `Task` I launched to do the receiving never closes.

Why doesn't the completion handler get called when the web socket is cancelled?

Comment: Hi, did you ever get a solution to this?

Comment: I'm afraid not. Currently I'm still allowing this to leak.

Answer (score 0):

Are you actually seeing a leak with the closure-based approach?

I see a leak when using the async version, but if I use the closure-version the `URLSessionWebSocketTask`-object is freed. I don't get any call to the closure, but for my use case that does not matter.

If I use the delegate on the session I will get a callback when the websocket is closed, but I have to call `session.invalidateAndCancel` when cleaning up.

I also needed to add `[weak self]` to the closure since I call my receive-function recursively, capturing self.